# Missing required parameters for [Route: admin.edit] [URI: customer/account/edit/{id}]

Tags: php, laravel

Is that form action there need to pass parameter for ID? 
Here is the route file web.php

```
Route::get('/customer/account/edit/{id}',['as'=>'admin.edit','uses'=>'AdminController@edit']);
```

Here is the view file create.blade.php

```
 <form action="{{ route('admin.edit') }}" method="POST">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="fieldset">
                   ........
                </div>
</form>
```

Comment: How come you are not using a post route to handle the form data?

Comment: `Route::get` and `method="POST"` means that your form will never reach that route.

Comment: Does your `AdminController@edit` has `function edit (Request $request, $id) { } ?`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set routr as post and You need to specify the route definition like below if id is an optional parameter

```
Route::post('/customer/account/edit/{id?}',['as'=>'admin.edit','uses'=>'AdminController@edit']);
```

Or else it should be like below

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.edit', ['id' => $id]) }}" method="POST">
                {{csrf_field()}}
                <div class="fieldset">
                   ........
                </div>
</form>
```